# How to add vertical tabs (like the product page) to a custom magento admin form

Tags: php, magento

There are many tutorials to adding extra tabs to the product page but I am struggling to find information on how I can create tabs on a new form from scratch. I have looked at the following resources but the information presented doesn't seem to be very clear or my magento isn't good enough to understand it yet:

1. http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/module-development-series-magento-admin-module-part3
2. [how to create multiple tab in magento custom module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952766/how-to-create-multiple-tab-in-magento-custom-module)

I am trying to emulate the tab system that runs vertically down the left side of the product section but on a custom form.

Are there any references out there on how this should be done (similar to the official magento one explaining how to create an admin module)?

p.s I haven't posted code as anything I have is directly from the tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up working through the excellencemagentoblog version and have successfully got tabs working. The examples given aren't exactly straight forward unless you understand the magento structure really well but the information within the article is adequate enough to work through.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?